# Rubinius Syntax Errors

Tags: ruby, lambda, ruby-1.9, rubinius, locomotivecms

While working with [LocomotiveCMS](http://www.locomotivecms.com/) using [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) I ran into a bunch of syntax errors. All were along the lines of `expecting '|'`. No one was posting [issues](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/issues) about this so I figured I would ask: How do I resolve these issues? Is this a problem with Rubinius?

Answer (score 1):

First off, LocomotiveCMS only supports the "last version of Ruby" (Ruby 1.9.2 and greater). [View the requirements section](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/installation/requirements).

Rubinius defaults to Ruby 1.8.7 ([view on rvm.io](https://rvm.io/interpreters/rbx/)). If you look at the lines where most of these syntax errors occur like in `app/models/locomotive/page.rb` they are most likely in "lambdas" which aren't supported until Ruby 1.9.

To resolve, you can make Rubinius (rbx) use Ruby 1.9 in two ways:

1. Use [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to reinstall rbx using Ruby 1.9 as the default:

   ```
   rvm reinstall rbx --1.9
   ```

   Note: if rvm complains about bad arguments [upgrade rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading/) using `rvm get master` or `rvm get stable`.
2. Or, if you don't want to completely reinstall rbx, you can set an environment variable in the directory which you'll be calling Rubinius, like in the rails root directory.

   ```
   export RBXOPT=-X19
   ```

   You can check that the environment variable is set by using `rbx -v` to check the Ruby version. It should return something like:

   ```
   rubinius 2.0.0.rc1 (1.9.3 release ...)
   ```

   Note: If you are running Rubinius from another directory you will need to set this option again.